# How to edit info.plist in expo?

Tags: ios, expo, info.plist

I submitted an .ipa file to ios app connect and received a request to modify the permission string in info.plist.
I worked with expo, and as a result of searching, app.json was told to write as follows.

```
"ios": {
  "infoPlist": {
   "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "Allow access to photo to upload photos from your library."
  },
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "buildNumber": "1.1.0",
  
},
```

After writing the following, even though I submitted it as command"expo build:ios", it was rejected with the same request for modification.
Is this method wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: Please share which is exactly the error message you get in App Store